# Adding custom validation on checkout field country

Tags: validation, magento2, checkout

I need to add a validation on the country field in all place where it can be used.

For registration or address editing it work fine but in checkout I tried several method but nothing worked. I want the validation on the field of the new shipping address form.

1. I add my validation in an js file `countryValidation.js` :
   Same script for registration or edit address and it work fine

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/validation',
    'mage/translate',
    'domReady!'
], function($){
    'use strict';
    return function(validator) {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            "validate-country",
            function(value, element) {
                if (value === "FR") {
                    var zipValue = $('input[name="postcode"]').val();
                    if (zipValue) {
                        return !(zipValue.startsWith("97") || zipValue.startsWith("98"));
                    }
                }

                return true;
            },
            $.mage.__("You cannot choose France for DOM-TOM Zip Code")
        );
        return validator;
    }
});
```

2. I registered it in `requirejs-config.js` in my module :

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator': {
                'Gone_Customer/js/countryValidation': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

3. For adding validation to checkout method I tried different method
   -> Method A : With a plugin

```
class AddCountryValidation
{
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        // Country ID
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['country_id']['validation']['validate-country'] = true;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

-> Method B : add validation rule in attribute
In `customer_eav_attribute` in attribute `country_id` for `validate_rules` I added `{"validate-country": true}`

When I validate the form I have no validation error when I should have one.

Can you tell me if I'm missing something please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your response in the meantime I found something that worked.
I had to do a seperate js validation only for checkout :

```
define(['mage/translate', "jquery"], function($t, $) {
    'use strict';

    return function(rules) {
        rules['validate-country'] = {
            handler: function (value) {
                if (value === "FR") {
                    var zipValue = $('input[name="postcode"]').val();
                    if (zipValue) {
                        return !(zipValue.startsWith("97") || zipValue.startsWith("98"));
                    }
                }

                return true;
            },
            message: $t('You cannot choose France for DOM-TOM Zip Code')
        };
        return rules;
    };
});
```

And in my mixin I change `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator` for `Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules` then my plugin method was working !

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'jquery/validate'
], function($){
  'use strict';
  return function(validator) {
      validator.addRule(
          "validate-country",
          function(value) {
              if (value === "FR") {
                  var zipValue = $('input[name="postcode"]').val();
                  if (zipValue) {
                      return !(zipValue.startsWith("97") || zipValue.startsWith("98"));
                  }
              }
              return false;
          },
          $.mage.__("You cannot choose France for DOM-TOM Zip Code")
      );
      return validator;
  }
  });
```

I have used return false you can modify according to your need.Tested on version 2.2.2